# Para que serve o underline em literais numéricos?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem

Qual é o uso do underline (_) nas situações abaixo:

```
float pi =  3.14159_26535_89793_23846;
long bytes = 00101001_00100110_01100001;
int n = 1____________________1;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Serve apenas para deixar a leitura mais fácil. O compilador os ignora. Por exemplo, isso:

```
private long milisegundosNoDia = 86_400_000;
```

É mais fácil de se ler (por um humano) do que isso:

```
private long milisegundosNoDia = 86400000;
```

Comment: Que *feature* legal, toda linguagem deveria ter isso :)

Comment: @Renan né? Fiquei frustrado quando descobri que não existia em C

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Qualquer *feature* na linguagem pode ser abusada ou utilizada de forma incorreta para deixar mais difícil, esta daqui não é exceção.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger 